# Ubuntu 20.04.3 - Asus ROG Maximus XIII Hero & Microphone

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, asus, microphone

I need a little help for fixing my Microphone in my new Ubuntu pc. It seems to me that it is not recognized by Ubuntu.

```
$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 43c8 (rev 11)
```

and the pcm result is:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/pcm
00-00: USB Audio : USB Audio : capture 1
01-03: HDMI 0 : HDMI 0 : playback 1
02-00: USB Audio : USB Audio : playback 1 : capture 1
02-01: USB Audio : USB Audio #1 : playback 1 : capture 1
02-02: USB Audio : USB Audio #2 : playback 1 : capture 1
02-03: USB Audio : USB Audio #3 : playback 1
```

I have found the model of the sound card: **ASUSTek Computer 0x19ac**

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b05:19ac ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB Audio
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0b05 ASUSTek Computer, Inc.
  idProduct          0x19ac 
  bcdDevice            0.15
  iManufacturer           3 Generic
  iProduct                1 USB Audio
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
```

...

```
  AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                12
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
    bTerminalID             1
    wTerminalType      0x0201 Microphone
    bAssocTerminal          0
    bNrChannels             2
    wChannelConfig     0x0000
    iChannelNames           0 
    iTerminal               0
```

check the system messages have I found this situation:

```
dmesg | egrep -i "alsa|snd"
[    1.905374] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.919457] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x000f0000
[    2.955569] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC1D0: HDMI ATI/AMD: no speaker allocation for ELD
[    3.923608] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, disabling MSI: last cmd=0x000f0000
[    4.935465] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Codec #0 probe error; disabling it...
[    4.940665] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: No i915 binding for Intel HDMI/DP codec
[    4.941371] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Cannot probe codecs, giving up
[    9.389681] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
```

Proc Sound check result:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card0/pcm0c/info
card: 0
device: 0
subdevice: 0
stream: CAPTURE
id: USB Audio
name: USB Audio
subname: subdevice #0
class: 0
subclass: 0
subdevices_count: 1
subdevices_avail: 0
```

[image]

If I plug my microphone with its jack in my computer I can see the selection here:

[image]

Could you please help me to configure this microphone?

After some investigation the audio card is ALC4080 and other user have the same issue. See at [Realtek® ALC4080 Codec Front Jack doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384500/realtek-alc4080-codec-front-jack-doesnt-work)

thanks

Comment: hey i have the same problem almost i think if i select the front output and select the front input and play the test sound on the output the volume of the input reflects the output so the output is swapped some how as an input device on my end . and i don't know how to fix it yet .

Answer (score 0):

hey i have the same problem almost i think if i select the front output and select the front  input and play the test sound on the output the volume of the input reflects the output so the output is swapped some how as an input device on my end . and i don't know how to fix it yet .
i think you need to write Udev rules for Alsa like on this page https://alsa.opensrc.org/Udev  for Mapping the correct channel in and outputs pacmd list-sources detects two Asus devices in my case on the same card1 and creating a .asoundrc file in the root of your home folder i think this is what i did so far for playback internal line out using pulseaudio and rhythembox and recording the internal microphone using audacity
created a udev rules file called 95-static-soundcard-name.rules
with this content

```
# For alsa card naming (check with `cat /proc/asound/cards`)

SUBSYSTEM!="sound", GOTO="alsa_naming_end" ACTION!="add", GOTO="alsa_naming_end"

DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/sound/card1", ATTR{id}="Realtek"


LABEL="alsa_naming_end"


# For pulsaudio card naming (check with `pacmd list-sources`)

SUBSYSTEM!="sound", GOTO="pa_naming_end" ACTION!="change", GOTO="pa_naming_end" KERNEL!="card1", GOTO="pa_naming_end"


DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/sound/card1", ENV{PULSE_NAME}="Realtek ALC4082"

LABEL="pa_naming_end"
```

and in the .asoundrc file in the home folder I putted

```
defaults.pcm.card 1
defaults.pcm.device 1
defaults.ctl.card 1
```

for recording audio in audacity type in a terminal after installation

```
sudo snap connect audacity:alsa
```

and select the right source.
in my case it was USB Audio: #2 (hw:1,2)

the .asoundrc is for playing audio thru pulseaudio only , if you leave it out of your home directory you should be able to record and playback in audacity depending the alsa output and input you select for using the front microphone input as default source for recording in pulseaudio related software like webcam applications you can modify the .asoundrc file with the device not set for output but input so number 2 in my case did that trick the only problem i still have is that i can not default both devices together so i need to log out and in when i switch the devices around .To bad that the .asoudrc file doesn't accept the the normal way of setting the default devices like with pcm.!default because it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: thanks Pilot6 for the Edit ;)