# Asus rog strix z690-a gaming wifi d4 No sound in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, asus, 22.04

After installing Ubuntu 20.04, I noticed I have no sound at all. I also installed 22.04 thinking maybe the newer version has fixed this issue, which turned out to be wrong. 22.04 also suffers from this issue as well.
Here is the output of `lspci -v` in case it matters:

```
hossein@hossein-pc:~$ sudo lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4668 (rev 02)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at <ignored> (32-bit, non-prefetchable)

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 460d (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 121
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00006000-00006fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: 84000000-850fffff [size=17M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000004000000000-0000004011ffffff [size=288M]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [98] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [220] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [a30] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [a90] Data Link Feature <?>
    Capabilities: [a9c] Physical Layer 16.0 GT/s <?>
    Capabilities: [edc] Lane Margining at the Receiver <?>
    Capabilities: [adc] Extended Capability ID 0x2a
    Capabilities: [b0c] Extended Capability ID 0x2b
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 467d (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at 4014210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Designated Vendor-Specific <?>
    Capabilities: [110] Designated Vendor-Specific <?>
    Capabilities: [120] Designated Vendor-Specific <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-pmt
    Kernel modules: intel_pmt

00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at 4012000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Memory at 82000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Memory at 4014100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=19 Masked-
    Capabilities: [90] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [e0] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: vmd
    Kernel modules: vmd

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae0 (rev 11) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 147
    Memory at 4014200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [b0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=00 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 7aa7 (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at 4014220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]
    Memory at 4014229000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3

00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 7af0 (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0074
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at 401421c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable- Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [164] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0010 Rev=0 Len=014 <?>
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 7acc (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Memory at 4014226000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 7acd (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40
    Memory at 4014227000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:15.2 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 7ace (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at 4014228000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae8 (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 167
    Memory at 4014225000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [a4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae2 (rev 11) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    DeviceName: Onboard - SATA
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 146
    Memory at 86900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at 86903000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 7050 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 7040 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 7020 [size=32]
    Memory at 86902000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1a.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7ac8 (rev 11) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00005fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: 85b00000-864fffff [size=10M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000004014300000-00000040144fffff [size=2M]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [98] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7ab8 (rev 11) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: 85100000-85afffff [size=10M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000004014500000-00000040146fffff [size=2M]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [98] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7ab9 (rev 11) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: 86800000-868fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [98] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [220] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [a30] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [a90] Data Link Feature <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7abb (rev 11) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: 86500000-866fffff [size=2M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [98] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [220] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [a30] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [a90] Data Link Feature <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7ab4 (rev 11) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=06, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: 86700000-867fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [98] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [220] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [a30] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [a90] Data Link Feature <?>
    Capabilities: [a9c] Physical Layer 16.0 GT/s <?>
    Capabilities: [edc] Lane Margining at the Receiver <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a84 (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 7ad0 (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 168
    Memory at 4014218000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 4014000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 7aa3 (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at 4014224000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 7aa4 (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at 80800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2206 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 403f
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 169
    Memory at 84000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at 4010000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 6000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 85000000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [bb0] Resizable BAR <?>
    Capabilities: [c1c] Physical Layer 16.0 GT/s <?>
    Capabilities: [d00] Lane Margining at the Receiver <?>
    Capabilities: [e00] Data Link Feature <?>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1aef (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 403f
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at 85080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [160] Data Link Feature <?>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

04:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 154
    I/O ports at 3050 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 3040 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 3030 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 3020 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=32]
    Memory at 86800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512]
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 15f3 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 87d2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at 86500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at 86600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=5 Masked-
    Capabilities: [a0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 04-42-1a-ff-ff-31-84-6b
    Capabilities: [1c0] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [1f0] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [1e0] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: igc
    Kernel modules: igc

06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a809 (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a801
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, NUMA node 0
    Memory at 86700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=13 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [158] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [168] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [188] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [190] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
```

As you can see, it seems the audio devices are detected, yet still there is no sound whatsoever!
How can I fix this issue?

### Update 1:

I noticed the sound seems ok from the back panel, but the front panel has no sound. I checked and front panel and backpanel both have sound under windows, but front panel doesnt work in ubuntu only! how is this possible? is this still a driver issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A user kindly posted an answer and linked to this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/p7xbna/no_headphone_sound_alc4080/) which contains a workaround to fix this issue. He somehow deleted his answer after a few minutes. I found my workaround at the end of the mentioned reddit-post which is a one liner!

What solved my issue was the workaround explained in this [link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2011484#p2011484).
what I did was to simply run the following command :
First I used this command :

```
pacmd load-module module-alsa-sink name='Front Panel Headphone' device=1 device_id=2 control='PCM',1
```

which didnt work, but after running the following command the fornt jack started working just fine:

```
pacmd load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:Audio,1 control='PCM',1
```

the `device` name had to be `hw:Audio`, as I got that from running `alsa-info`
(here's [my info](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=ca4308c94303b5e00d947c559a83f3204a97e9dc) for the reference)

```
!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0x4014218000 irq 184
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0x85080000 irq 17
 2 [Audio          ]: USB-Audio - USB Audio
                      Generic USB Audio at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, high speed
```

After that, I noticed a new entry in the settings/sound section, and both the front and back have sound thankfully.

Comment: This solution worked for me running Ubuntu 22.04 on a MSI z690-A motherboard.  After rebooting.  And for more details I followed this https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2011484#p2011484

Comment: Wow, works like a charm. Motherboard: ROG Strix Z790-F Gaming WiFi and Ubuntu: 22.04

Answer (score 4):

EDIT:THIS ANSWER WORKED FOR ME! please see this answer below: https://askubuntu.com/a/1420082/1602652 . I ran both commands and now I have sound on Ubuntu 22.04 with a Z690 mobo and kernel 5.18. Seems like it's kernel agnostic because OP's answer has 5.15 kernel.

Also if you want this fix to persist through reboot, then add the following near the bottom of the /etc/pulse/default.pa file: `pacmd load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:Audio,1 control=PCM,1`

make sure to not have single or double quotes in the file

I have the same issue as you with the same hardware. From what I've read is it looks like the sound card we have is not supported by the kernel yet or snd-hda-intel driver for it are not loading properly.

We might be out of luck for a while. I've literally tried everything from editing the alsa-base.conf file to updating my kernel to 5.18.2 and nothing has worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also did lots of testing to no avail. I even sent an email to realtek but got no reply as of yet. contacted Asus support as well, but they said, since we only support windows 10/11, we cant help you with linux related issues!

Comment: no worries and hopefully Realtek will get back to you. just mostly wanted to let you know you're not alone in getting this resolved. I've joined the alsa mailing list too because looks like they are the ones who handle all the audio stuff in the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

I've upvoted @Hossein and @jmose, thank you for getting me where I needed to be!  I finally managed to get it all working.  For anyone who might stumble across this post having the same or similar [issues](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/z0929h/front_headset_jack_on_debian_with_asus_rog_strix/), I'll document the full process that I went through multiple times to get the exact steps from when you arrive at the Debian desktop having installed from ISO.  I know a lot isn't useful to the OP, but it might help others. When I was on the latest daily build, I had Pro Audio / ProAudio as a 'driver', but I don't have it in the below, and everything appears to work correctly.

**Motherboard**: ASUS ROG STRIX X670E-E Motherboard

**Integrated Wi-Fi**: Intel ® Wi-Fi 6E AX210 (Model: AX210NGW):

**Integrated Audio**: ROG SupremeFX 7.1 Surround Sound High Definition Audio CODEC ALC4080

**GPU**: NVIDIA 3070

**ISO Used**: debian-live-11.5.0-amd64-cinnamon+nonfree.iso (Kernel 5.10.0-18-amd64)

## Switch to root user

```
#Switch user to root
su -l

#Add your account username to the SUDO list
adduser YourAccount sudo
```

## Get Grub to detect other OSs on other partitions

With more recent versions of Grub, I understand they are blocking the searching of OSs on other partitions because of a security issue.  This will enable the search, detect the install, then disable the search, so you will have all OSs detected from the beginning.

While still running as root, Edit GRUB

```
nano /etc/default/grub
```

Add this to the bottom

> #Enable the prober to detect OSs on other partitions
>
> GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

Save and Exit - Ctrl+s, Ctrl+x

Get Grub to update the OS boot list

```
sudo update-grub
```

Prevent Grub from finding other OSs

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Comment out the PROBER line

Save and Exit - Ctrl+s, Ctrl+x

## Update sources and packages

While still running as root, edit the sources list

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

(can also use `apt edit-sources`)

Delete everything and add in the following:

> ##------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> ##2022-11-26 Added by Aubs to get the non-free and other non-stable packages
>
> #Use the UK Mirror
>
> deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main contrib non-free
>
> deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib
> non-free
>
> deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main
> contrib non-free
>
> #Proposed updates for the next point release
>
> deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian bullseye-proposed-updates main contrib non-free
>
> #Updates for BACKPORTS
>
> deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main contrib non-free
>
> #Updates for TESTING
>
> deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
>
> #Updates for UNSTABLE - Is Unstable the same as Testing??
>
> #deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
>
> ##------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Save and Exit - Ctrl+s, Ctrl+x

Add preferences to only give updates from stable

`nano /etc/apt/preferences`

Add in the following

> Package: *
>
> Pin: release a=bullseye
>
> Pin-Priority: 500
>
> Package: *
>
> Pin:release a=bullseye-backports
>
> Pin-Priority: 400
>
> Package: *
>
> Pin: release a=proposed-updates
>
> Pin-Priority: 300
>
> Package: *
>
> Pin:release a=testing
>
> Pin-Priority: 200

Save and Exit - Ctrl+s, Ctrl+x

Check for updates

```
apt update
```

Check what needs to be updated

```
apt list --upgradable
```

Update everything

```
apt upgrade
```

Install some useful packages

```
apt install whois wget git
```

Reboot

```
reboot
```

To make sure you're not getting any unstable updates, comment out the non-stable repositories (bullseye-proposed-updates / bullseye-backports / testing / unstable), run `apt update`/`apt upgrade`, un-comment them again, run `apt update` and there should not be any remaining packages to update (`All packages are up to date.`).  This means you're not getting any non-stable updates.

## Update Kernel to 6.0 (via backports)

```
uname -rv
```

From the 11.5 Cinnamon ISO

> 5.10.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.140-1 (2022-09-02)

```
sudo apt list -a linux-image-amd64 linux-headers-amd64
```

> linux-headers-amd64/testing 6.0.8-1 amd64
>
> linux-headers-amd64/bullseye-backports,now 6.0.3-1~bpo11+1 amd64
>
> linux-headers-amd64/stable-security,proposed-updates 5.10.149-2 amd64
>
> linux-headers-amd64/stable 5.10.140-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
>
> linux-image-amd64/testing 6.0.8-1 amd64
>
> linux-image-amd64/bullseye-backports,now 6.0.3-1~bpo11+1 amd64
>
> linux-image-amd64/stable-security,proposed-updates 5.10.149-2 amd64
>
> linux-image-amd64/stable 5.10.140-1 amd64 [installed]

```
sudo apt -t bullseye-backports install linux-image-amd64 linux-headers-amd64
sudo reboot
```

Once booted, check versions again

```
uname -rv
```

After Kernel upgrade

> 6.0.0-0.deb11.2-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.0.3-1~bpo11+1 (2022-10-29)

## Setting up Audio

Check the latest version of alsa-utils in all repositories

```
sudo apt list -a alsa-utils
```

> alsa-utils/testing 1.2.7-1 amd64
>
> alsa-utils/stable,stable,now 1.2.4-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

Install the latest version from Testing

```
sudo apt -t testing install alsa-utils
alsaucm reload
```

Check the latest version of pulseaudio in all repositories

```
sudo apt list -a pulseaudio
```

> pulseaudio/testing,now 16.1+dfsg1-2+b1 amd64
>
> pulseaudio/stable 14.2-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]

Install the latest version from Testing

```
sudo apt -t testing install pulseaudio
sudo reboot now
```

The next steps taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1420082/689452)

Check which device is being used, the Device Name is used to set the [device=hw:Audio] next

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

> 0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
>
> 1 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
>
> 2 [Audio          ]: USB-Audio - USB Audio
>
> Generic USB Audio at usb-0000:10:00.0-6, high speed

```
pacmd load-module module-alsa-sink name='Front Panel Headphone' device=1 device_id=2 control='PCM',1
pacmd load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:Audio,1 control='PCM',1
```

Edit the default Pulse Audio config to make sure audio works after each reboot

```
sudo nano /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Add to the bottom (there's only one line of code, but the rest of the comments are there to remind you where it came from in future!)

> ##------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> ##Aubs added 2022-11-26 to retain audio between reboots
>
> ##Taken from https://askubuntu.com/a/1420082/689452
>
> ##$ cat /proc/asound/cards
>
> ##OUTPUT>> 2 [Audio          ]: USB-Audio - USB Audio
>
> ##$ pacmd load-module module-alsa-sink name='Front Panel Headphone' device=1 device_id=2 control='PCM',1
>
> ##Make sure [device=hw:Audio] matches the above OUTPUT
>
> ##$ pacmd load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:Audio,1 control='PCM',1
>
> load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:Audio,1 control=PCM,1
>
> ##------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Save and Exit - Ctrl+s, Ctrl+x

The next steps taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1429766/689452)

Download the latest alsa-ucm-conf

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-ucm-conf
cd alsa-ucm-conf
```

Take a backup of the existing ucm2 folder

```
sudo mv /usr/share/alsa/ucm2 /usr/share/alsa/ucm2_bak/
```

Create a sym link from the download to the live folder - Might be best moving ucm2 to the live location

```
sudo ln -s `pwd`/ucm2 /usr/share/alsa/ucm2
```

Reload alsa, kill PulseAudio and restart its daemon

```
alsaucm reload
pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -D
```

**alsamixer** (Alsa Mixer) and **pavucontrol** (PulseAudio Volume Control utility) are useful.  *Don't use the backports or test versions though as they break!*

```
sudo apt install alsamixer pavucontrol
```

- Run `alsamixer`, press F6, select sound card, ensure it is visible. Esc to exit.
- Run `pavucontrol`, View which profiles are assigned to each device.
- Run `cinnamon-settings sound` (or open the sound settings) see audio is configured correctly.

## Install  Nvidia (Get the latest Drivers Without Nouveau)

**OPTION A**

NOTE: Check if the latest version available via APT is the same version as the download, could be better to install it through APT !

```
sudo apt list -a nvidia-driver
```

Then install with

```
sudo apt -t testing install nvidia-driver
```

**OPTION B**

Otherwise, Instructions [HERE](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/525.53/README/index.html)

This method install NVIDIA using the latest drivers (or beta) and removes Nouveau / OpenCL etc.

Download the latest drivers from [HERE](https://www.nvidia.co.uk/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-uk)

The next steps taken from [here](https://hashcat.net/faq/wrongdriver)

Remove all remnants of NVIDIA and others

```
sudo apt remove nvidia-driver
sudo apt purge nvidia-driver
sudo apt purge nvidia*
```

Find all packages installed that provide a libOpenCL, then purge them
sudo dpkg -S libOpenCL

I had to remove the following
sudo apt purge ocl-icd-libopencl1

Remove any left over files

```
find / -name libOpenCL\* -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
sudo apt remove hashcat
```

Manually remove any apps found with the below:

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep 'OpenCL CL SDK CUDA'
```

I didn't have any to remove

```
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install ocl-icd-libopencl1 opencl-headers clinfo
sudo reboot
```

Prevent Nouveau from starting

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-aubs-disable-nouveau.conf
```

Add in

> #generated by aubs for NVIDIA install
>
> blacklist nouveau
>
> options nouveau modeset=0

Save and Exit - Ctrl+s, Ctrl+x

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
```

It might not boot to desktop, connect monitor to a HDMI port on the motherboard instead of the GPU, then log in

If the screen doesn't come on, when the grub menu appears, press `e`
Then add `nomodeset` to the end of the Linux line, finally F10 to boot

Ctrl+Alt+F1 and log in

```
sudo service lightdm stop
cd ~/Documents
```

Install the latest driver, but check the file name matches the one downloaded

```
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.53.run
sudo reboot
```