# How to make Ubuntu 20.04 work with Realtek ALC4080

Tags: sound

My mother board is ASUS ROS STRIX Z590-A Gaming WiFi that comes with a Realtek ALC4080 USB Audio chip, it does not work on Ubuntu 20.04 with 5.15 kernel. For headphone, I could get the sound from it only if it has been plugged in before booting, which means that I no long get any playback sound if I reseat the headphone while the system is running. Headphone mic does not work at all with either front panel or rear panel. BTW, headphone and mic can always be detected as shown in `pavucontrol`.

The front panel behaves a bit differently. Every time I re-plug the headphone in the 3.5mm jack on the front panel, it is detected as "Headphone (plugged in)" and the USB Audio profile is switched to "Analog Stereo Duplex" in `pavucontrol`. I could get the playback sound only by running `aplay -D plughw:2,1 <path-to-audio-file>`. but not from other applications, e.g. `ffplay`, that is configured to use pulseaudio as backend.

This is the output of `inix -A`:

```
Audio:     Device-1: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel
           Device-2: NVIDIA driver: snd_hda_intel
           Device-3: ASUSTek USB Audio type: USB driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.15.0-88-generic
```

But `Device-1` is not accessible from `alsamixer`. The kernel log may imply the cause:

```
[    1.700089] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    1.702803] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
[    1.702807] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    2.712442] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x000f0000
[    3.724433] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, disabling MSI: last cmd=0x000f0000
[    4.732444] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Codec #0 probe error; disabling it...
[    4.737657] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: No i915 binding for Intel HDMI/DP codec
[    4.738438] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Cannot probe codecs, giving u
```

Additional information:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Audio [USB Audio], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Audio [USB Audio], device 1: USB Audio [USB Audio #1]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Audio [USB Audio], device 2: USB Audio [USB Audio #2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Audio [USB Audio], device 4: USB Audio [USB Audio #4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I finally gave a try to the approach from [realtek-alc4080-codec-front-jack-doesnt-work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384500/realtek-alc4080-codec-front-jack-doesnt-work), adding the ALC4080 USB-Audio configuration, but got no luck. As long as the headphone get reseated, I no longer get any sound.

It seems that old version of alsa shipped by Ubuntu 20.04 is not able to handle ALC4080 correctly, but I have no idea how to easily get the new version of alsa while keeping the system is not broken.

Comment: If they are detected by pavucontrol, then can you adjust the volume and enable assign them from the pavucontrol settings?

Comment: @mchid, I can adjust the volume as I like, but I cannot get to know if the adjustment works as I have no playback sound from my headphone.

Comment: On a side note, Device 1 appears to be HDMI and I think you would need to run `alsamixer -c 0` or `alsamixer -c 1` etc. Unfortunately, `alsamixer` is not very helpful even when you get HDMI to display as there are usually no volume controls, just channels, although you can mute and unmute the channels.

Comment: Also, after you reset the headphones, have you checked the modules to see if they're all loaded still? So: `lsmod | grep 'hid-generic\|snd-usb-audio\|usbhid'` and if any of those three are not listed, then run `sudo modprobe` for each one that is missing. Example: `sudo modprobe usbhid`

Comment: @mchid. I updated my post, When my headphone is plugged in the 3.5mm jack on the front panel, dragging the volume slide in `pavucontrol` actually adjusts the `PCM Front`, `PCM Rear`, `PCM Center`, `PCM Woofer` and `PCM Side` together in `alsamixer`, which has no effect on the `aplay` command. The volume of `aplay` is controlled by the `PCM 1` in `alsamixer`

Comment: @mchid `hid-generic`, `snd-usb-audio` and `usbhid` are all loaded. For `alsamixer`, I need to run `alsamixer -c2` for the USB Audio device. I've switched off the profile for "HDA NVIDIA" (Device 1)  in `pavucontrol`

Comment: [Another trick would be to reset pulseaudio after you reset the device.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15223/how-can-i-restart-pulseaudio-without-having-to-logout) Usually, `pulseaudio -k` will kill and then automatically respawn pulseaudio. If it doesn't restart automatically, then run `pulseaudio --start` although again, that's usually not necessary. Lastly, `sudo alsa force-reload` reloads alsa although, not sure how much that will help but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @mchid I've googled a lot and tried all I had got except for installing a new version of alsa from source, none of them really helps.

Comment: If you try to build alsa and run into issues and then back out, after you uninstall what you compiled, see the [last two commands of this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/800280) to get pulse working again.