# No sound on ALC4080 and Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: sound, 22.04, realtek

A few days ago I upgraded my PC with a `MSI MAG Z790 TOMAHAWK WIFI` motherboard, which has `ALC4080` audio processor. I then installed a fresh `Ubuntu 22.04.3`.

After that the system doesn't seem to see the audio device responsible for jack output, so the output doesn't work at all. The only way for me to get any sound from the PC is to use bluetooth headphones or external USB sound card.

I tried a few different solutions I found, e.g. this ones: [Realtek® ALC4080 Codec Front Jack doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384500/realtek-alc4080-codec-front-jack-doesnt-work)
but none of them worked for me.

Some information:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0620 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.2 Hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0451:8140 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB8041 4-Port Hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0451:8140 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB8041 4-Port Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0620 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.2 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0451:8142 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB8041 4-Port Hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 041e:409d Creative Technology, Ltd Live! Cam Sync 1080p
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0451:8142 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB8041 4-Port Hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 051d:0002 American Power Conversion Uninterruptible Power Supply
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 3299:754a HF-50 Microphone  HF-50 Microphone 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 1462:7d91 Micro Star International MYSTIC LIGHT 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0db0:a74b Micro Star International USB Audio
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ alsaucm -i
alsaucm: Interacive mode - 'q' to quit
alsaucm>> open USB-Audio
ALSA lib parser.c:243:(error_node) UCM is not supported for this USB device (Creative Technology Ltd. Live! Cam Sync 1080p at usb-0000:00:14.0-9.4.3, high s @ USB041e:409d)
ALSA lib main.c:1412:(snd_use_case_mgr_open) error: failed to import USB-Audio use case configuration -6
alsaucm: error failed to open sound card USB-Audio: No such device or address
^^^ error, try again
```

Sound management panel:

[image]
[image]

Any help will be appreciated!